# How can i convert a statelistDrawable to bitmapdrawable in android

Tags: android

How can i convert a **state list Drawable** to **bitmap drawable** in android.
I want to convert a statelist drawable into bitmap drawable.

Comment: or i can accept this also - well i am getting the list of installed apps if my app doesnot have icon i.e. icon value is null or my icon is of statelist drawable type ,then i want to set the icon to android launcher icon how can i do that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around if i find any icon whose type is other then bitmap drawable then use this code
here `searchResult.getIcon()` is my icon value

```
  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(searchResult.getIcon().getIntrinsicWidth(),searchResult.getIcon().getIntrinsicHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap); 
            searchResult.getIcon().setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
            searchResult.getIcon().draw(canvas);
            itemIconBitmap = bitmap;
            e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use toBitmap or casting the current drawable

```
(stateListDrawable as? StateListDrawable)?.let { drawable ->
                            (drawable.current as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
                        }
```